# provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable. using valuechanges

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

Hello am having the following issue when subscribing to valuechanges of form group
***provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable. using valuechanges***

In my class component i have the following set up where i initialize a list of items that need to display in modal popup and only for the nextLevel field i have need to have a formcontrol so that this value is editable and when there is a change in the input fields, it should take the latest updated values inserted from this formcontrol which has key nextLevel in my formarray.

Am tried to subscribe to the formgroup itself, this is throwing the error provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected....

```
export interface StudentFieldDialogConfig{
  values: DialogValue[];
}

export interface DialogValue {
  currentLevel?: string;
  dateFrom: string;
  nextLevel?: string;
}


@Input() public model: StudentFieldDialogConfig;
  public ngOnInit(): void {

    this.initStudentFieldsDialog();
    this.items = this.setDialogData();
    this.listenFieldChange();
  }


  public initStudentFieldsDialog(): void {
    this.model?.values.map(studentValue=> {
      this.myFormGroup = this.setStudentFieldsFormGroup (studentValue);
    });
  }

  private setStudentFieldsFormGroup = (studentValue: studentValueHistory): FormGroup => {
    return this.formBuilder.group({
      studentFields: this.formBuilder.array([
        this.formBuilder.group({
          currentLevel: new FormControl(studentValue.currentLevel),
          dateFrom: new FormControl(studentValue.dateFrom),
          nextLevel: new FormControl(studentValue.nextLevel),
        }),
      ]),
    });
  };

public listenFieldChange(): void {
  this.myFormGroup?.valueChanges.pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$)).subscribe((value: unknown) => {
    console.log(value)
    });
}



  private setDialogData(): DialogValue[] {
    return this.model?.values.map((studentValue, index) => {
      const studentFieldsControls = <FormArray>this.myFormGroup.controls['studentFields'];
      const itemFormGroup = <FormGroup>studentFieldsControls .controls[0];

      return {
        currentLevel: studentValue.currentLevel,
        dateFrom: studentValue.dateFrom,
        nextLevel: itemFormGroup.controls['nextLevel'].value,
      };
    });
  }
```

In my template

```
<students [items]=items>
    <ng-template let-formControl="formControl">
      {{ formControl.value }}
      <input[formControl]="formControl"/>
    </ng-template>
</students >
```

Comment: What is this.model? it looks like the this.model?.values is empty.

Comment: CharlieV I have posted in the question, it is  @Input from another component